# How to create a multilevel JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm consuming tweepy in order to get tweets and I want to push them in one JSON file like:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "text": "one tweet",
      "rts": 2,
      "favs": 17
    },
    {
      "text": "another tweet",
      "rts": 2,
      "favs": 17
    },
    {
      "text": "one last tweet",
      "rts": 2,
      "favs": 17
    }
  ]
}
```

So I use:

```
import json
json_serial = "tweet"
my_json = {
  'content': {
    "text": json_serial,
    "rt": '2',
    "favs": '3',
  }
}
print(json.dumps(my_json))
```

But this would give me one JSON per tweet and I want to know how can I create one JSON and put all the tweets in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you are asking for.
you need to append tweet data to content variable, then at the end you can write it to a file however you want to use it. It will generate a valid json.

```
import json
my_json = {"content": []}

tweets = ["one", "middle", "last"]
for tweet in tweets:
    dict_data = {
        "text": tweet,
        "rt": '2',
        "favs": '3',
    }

    my_json["content"].append(dict_data)
print(json.dumps(my_json,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

**Output**

```
{  
   "content":[  
      {  
         "text":"one",
         "rt":"2",
         "favs":"3"
      },
      {  
         "text":"middle",
         "rt":"2",
         "favs":"3"
      },
      {  
         "text":"last",
         "rt":"2",
         "favs":"3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, does this help?
How are you receiving the tweets, one at a time?

```
import json
json_serial = 'tweet'
my_json = { 
    'content': [
        {"text": "tweet one",
        "rt": '1',
        "favs":'3',
        },  
        {"text": "another tweet",
        "rt": '2',
        "favs":'9',
        },  
        {"text": "yet another tweet",
        "rt": '3',
        "favs":'6',
        },  
    ]   
}
print(json.dumps(my_json))


$ python json-python.py 
{"content": [{"rt": "2", "text": "tweet", "favs": "3"}, {"rt": "2", "text": "tweet", "favs": "3"}, {"rt": "2", "text": "tweet", "favs": "3"}]}
```